# SQL query giving incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have exported data from Excelsheet into SQL table (`Table_A`) having 200000 records and there is a another table having same values in (`Table_B`).
I get incorrect results if I execute below query

```
 SELECT [ColE]
      ,[ColL]
      ,[ColS]
      ,[ColP]
  FROM Table_A
  where
   [ColL]= 'KBC nr. 2044 af 2. march 2001'
```

Where the `'KBC nr. 2044 af 2. march 2001'` value is from `Table_B`
where as below query runs fine when `'KBC nr. 2044 af 2. march 2001'` is picked from the `Table_A`

```
SELECT [ColE]
   ,[ColL]
   ,[ColS]
   ,[ColP]
FROM Table_A
where
[ColL]= 'KBC nr. 2044 af 2. march 2001'
```

What could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: What are you asking here? Those 2 queries are the same.

Comment: What do you mean `is from Table_B` I don't see Table_B in either query?

Comment: Your data likely has typos in it.  Such as rogue white spaces or other errors from during your import.  *(In short, the query isn't wrong, the data in that table simply isn't what you think it is / want it to be.)*

Comment: @Larnu and @Charlieface: yes those 2 queries are the same but in the first query , I do not get the output as the text in the where clause is from `Table_B` which is having same data, whereas in the second query I do get the output as the text in the where clause is from the `Table_A` itself on which I am querying. 
 ColE|ColL  |ColS  | ColP|
   A1 |KBC nr. 2044 af 2. march 2001 |Test1 |Test2|
Both `Table_A `and `Table_B` have same data except that `Table_A ` is created by importing data from excel sheet

Comment: `Table_B` isn't referenced in *either* of those queries.

Comment: I have used the text  `KBC nr. 2044 af 2. march 2001` from Table_B into the query directly

Comment: @MatBailie : Is there any possible way to find out those errors? I checked in notepad++ View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters but no difference in either of the text from Table A and table B

Comment: a way to check would be to compare the hashbytes on the values you are referencing

Answer (score 0):

I guess some unprintable character might have gone in when the data moved from excel to sql server. To confirm this you could try using like condition and compare the hashbytes

```
--TableA Query output..
SELECT [ColE]
      ,[ColL]
      ,hashbytes('md5',[ColL]) as hash_result
      ,[ColS]
      ,[ColP]
  FROM Table_A
 where [ColL]  = 'KBC nr. 2044 af 2. march 2001' 

--TableB Query output using like condition..
SELECT [ColE]
      ,[ColL]
      ,hashbytes('md5',[ColL]) as hash_result
      ,[ColS]
      ,[ColP]
  FROM Table_B
 where [ColL]  like  'KBC nr. 2044%'
```

If the hash_result values are different i means the string when moved from Excel to SQL Server has got corrupted

Comment: Yes, thanks for your response, the hashes seem to be different.